# Removing arrows and brackets from php parsing results

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove all the array garbage from the output:

http://freebesttickets.info/spinner.php

so that i get a clean list with one ID perline instead of a bunch of arrows and brackets mixed with the IDs

My first attempt

```
<?php
$f = fopen ('http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/view/list/sort/fans/page1', 'r');
$page = '';
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
  $page .= $line;
}
fclose ($f);
preg_match_all('#(?:(?<=\bhref="/like_box\.php\?id=)|' .
                '(?<=\bsrc="https://graph\.facebook\.com/))\d+#i',
                $page, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);


print_r ($result);



?>
```

I also tried to take the output and paste it into a second file and use reg expressions to remove all the stuff between the brackets but no success

```
<?php
$string = "[0] => Array 0] => 20531316728 [1] => 20531316728 [2] => 56531631380 [3] => 56531631380 [4] => 7270241753 [5] => 7270241753 [6] => 10092511675 [7] => 10092511675 [8] => 45309870078 [9] => 45309870078 [10] =>";

echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string); // 'ABC '


?>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `<pre>` tags?

Comment: i did but i want the parenthesized numbers like [26] => gone

Comment: To what purpose? I hope you're not giving this to end users. And if you want another script to be able to read it, you're better off formatting it as [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

Comment: Just don't use `print_r()` if you don't want its output. You already have an array.

Answer (score 1):

Or even simpler:

```
print implode("\n", $result[0]);
```

in place of the [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to loop through the array and output everything this way:

```
for($i=0;$i<$result.length,$i++){
    echo $result[$i];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in /home/post4/public_html/freebesttickets.info/spinner.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using print_r( $result ) loop through it

```
foreach ( $result[0] as $id ) {
    echo $id . "\n";
}
```

Will give you a clean list one id per line
( watch source code of the browser output if you open it in a browser )